# Convert a date String to "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss" format in Android & Swift

Tags: java, android, ios, iphone, swift

I am getting a String in this format from the server

```
2015-06-18T05:05:00.880483Z
```

I need to convert this to `yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss` format, which should be a string. How can I achieve this in `Android` as well as `Swift-iOS`. Please help if you know how to do this in one platform. Thanks in advance.

Comment: On Android this string is result of getTime?

Comment: nope. I get this string from server in a JSON field.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *strigDate="json date"

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strigDate];



dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSString *stringNewDate=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: can you please translate to Swift. Sorry I am newbie.

Comment: oops, I don't think, so I get a lot of errors. I think you might want to look up on the syntax though.

Comment: It's objective c, not Swift ;)

Comment: It may be a trivial question but why do you write `MM` with capital letters? Is it important or can I write them as `mm` too?

Answer (score 1):

On Android use this code:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'");
String dateString = "2015-06-18T05:05:00.880483Z";


try {
Date date = df.parse(dateString);
df.applyPattern("yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss");
String result = df.format(date);

} catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let stringDate = "2015-06-18T05:05:00.880483Z"

let df = NSDateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ"
if let date = df.dateFromString(stringDate) {
    df.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
    let finalString = df.stringFromDate(date)
    println(finalString)
}
```

Comment: I have output like this. There is a prob with the month field input = 2015-06-25T02:31:56.997291Z output = 2015/31/25 10:31:56

Comment: I get "2015/06/18 02:05:00" it depends where you are located. Are you sure you are not using YYYY instead yyyy or mm instead of MM?

Comment: @KalaiArasi check you didn't get your `m` and `M`s confused when transcribing this answer.

Comment: (other comments as per my answer: you need to set the locale to avoid this code failing in certain regions; it'd be better to use `ZZZZZ` so that the formatter recognises the zone)

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, off the top of my head:

```
func convertDateFormat(original: String) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:SSSSSSZZZZZ"
    dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier; "en_us_POSIX")
    let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(yourString)

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
    return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
}
```

An alternative that just uses whatever format the user would normally display dates in, supposing you're using the final string for display and not for machine input would be to cut the final two lines and instead do:

```
let outputFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
outputFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle;
outputFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle;
return outputFormatter.stringFromDate(date);
```

That'll be twelve or twenty-four hours, it'll do days and months the natural way around for that user, it'll print in Arabic or will obey the Chinese calendar rather than the Gregorian, etc.

`NSDateFormatter` reserves the right to make some adjustments ro your format string based on user display preferences unless you explicitly set the locale as `en_us_POSIX`. Also notice that you're specufying a GMT time and the user's device won't necessarily be set to GMT. So the output string may show the local time as it was when it was that particular GMT time. If your server is incorrect about that final `z` then override it by setting the `timezone` to GMT on your output formatter.

Comment: do you something like this  
    func changeDateTimeToString(date:NSDate!) -> String
    {
        var dateFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter();
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
        dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_us_POSIX")
        var dt:String = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date);

        return dt;
    }

Comment: That would return an `NSDate` object; you need to convert it to another string using `NSDateFormatter`'s `stringFromDate`. iOS has this thing called an `NSDate` with a bit of a confusing name: they "represent a single point in time". So exactly what that prints as depends on your time zone, locale, etc. `NSDateFormatter` does concersions between strings and dates subject to a time zone, a locale and a calendar, all of which you can leave implicit but that's why the different things exist and how they relate.

Comment: Also, versus other gven answers; omit the locale only if you want failure in some regions. Use the `ZZZZZ` Specifier rather than swallowing the source `Z` as a fixed-format character to ensure the date formatter recognises the zone the original string came in, without hard coding it.

Answer (score 0):

```
let strigDate="json date"

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
let date=dateFormatter.dateFromString(strigDate)

dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss"
let stringNewDate=dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I got the date to that format. It does not match my current date and time. I am in Singapore.

Comment: @KalaiArasi your date has Z at the end. It means it is UTC time. You can't disconsider Z

Comment: Ok, how to I get my local time ? Is there a way to convert UTC to my Local time zone ?

Comment: By failing to set the locale, this code will fail for users with the 12-hour cloxk set. Such as Americans. See QA1480.

Comment: dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone() write this line after dateformarer initialization

Answer (score 0):

```
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
    let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(str)

    dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss"
    let dateStr = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date!)
    print("Date string is:::::\(dateStr)")
```